# Trying to access array offset on value of type null PHP 7.4

Tags: php

Buenas estoy teniendo problema con este código al querer ingresar con login desde la api de steam, arroja este error, el archivo en sidebar.php en la linea 104

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /public_html/app/page/general/sidebar.php on line 104
PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /public_html/app/page/general/sidebar.php on line 104

<div class="tooltip-sidebar box-button-srv-0" style=""><?php echo $Translate->get_translate_phrase( $Auth->user_auth[0]['rank'], 'ranks_' . $Auth->server_info[0]['ranks_pack'] )?></div>
```

Parte del código :

```
<div class="tooltip-sidebar box-button-srv-0" style=""><?php echo $Translate->get_translate_phrase( $Auth->user_auth[0]['rank'], 'ranks_' . $Auth->server_info[0]['ranks_pack'] )?></div>
<?php for ( $d = 1; $d < $Auth->user_rank_count; ++$d ):?>
    <div class="tooltip-sidebar box-button-srv-treeview-<?php echo $d?>"><?php echo $Translate->get_translate_phrase( $Auth->user_auth[$d]['rank'], 'ranks_' . $Auth->server_info[ 0 ]['ranks_pack'] )?></div>
<?php endfor;?>
<div class="tooltip-sidebar box-button-home"><?php echo $Translate->get_translate_phrase('_Home')?></div>
<?php
for ( $d = 0, $c = sizeof( $Modules->arr_module_init['sidebar'] ); $d < $c; $d++ ):
    if( ! empty( $Modules->array_modules[ $Modules->arr_module_init['sidebar'][ $d ] ]['sidebar'] ) ):
        for ( $_d = 0, $_c = sizeof( $Modules->array_modules[ $Modules->arr_module_init['sidebar'][ $d ] ]['sidebar'] ); $_d < $_c; $_d++ ):?>
            <div class="tooltip-sidebar box-button-<?php  print $d."-".$_d;?>">
                <?php if(substr( $Modules->array_modules[ $Modules->arr_module_init['sidebar'][ $d ] ]['sidebar'][ $_d ]['name'], 0, 1) == '_') {
                    if ($Translate->get_translate_module_phrase( $Modules->arr_module_init['sidebar'][ $d ],$Modules->array_modules[ $Modules->arr_module_init['sidebar'][ $d ] ]['sidebar'][ $_d ]['name']) == 'No Translation'){
                        print $Translate->get_translate_phrase($Modules->array_modules[ $Modules->arr_module_init['sidebar'][ $d ] ]['sidebar'][ $_d ]['name']);
                    } else {
                        print $Translate->get_translate_module_phrase( $Modules->arr_module_init['sidebar'][ $d ], $Modules->array_modules[ $Modules->arr_module_init['sidebar'][ $d ] ]['sidebar'][ $_d ]['name']);
                    }
                    }else{
                    print $Modules->array_modules[ $Modules->arr_module_init['sidebar'][ $d ] ]['sidebar'][ $_d ]['name'];
                    }?>
            </div>
<?php   endfor;
    endif;
endfor;?>
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: El código relevante al problema va en la pregunta, por favor edita y agregalo aqui

Comment: Listo, quite el enlace y deje el código